# How to call setServiceInfo Dynamically in AccessibilityService

Tags: android, service, accessibility

How to invoke setServiceInfo method in AccessibilityService on runtime

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    log("onServiceConnected");
    setServiceInfo();
}
```

I need to dynamically change the serviceInfo values on runtime based on certain scenarios. I could not find a way to restart the service or call setServiceInfo from another class.

Please suggest me on this, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code from ClockBackService.java in the API samples provided with the SDK:

```
/**
 * Sets the {@link AccessibilityServiceInfo} which informs the system how to
 * handle this {@link AccessibilityService}.
 *
 * @param feedbackType The type of feedback this service will provide.
 * <p>
 *   Note: The feedbackType parameter is an bitwise or of all
 *   feedback types this service would like to provide.
 * </p>
 */
private void setServiceInfo(int feedbackType) {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    // We are interested in all types of accessibility events.
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    // We want to provide specific type of feedback.
    info.feedbackType = feedbackType;
    // We want to receive events in a certain interval. (milliseconds)
    info.notificationTimeout = EVENT_NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS;
    // We want to receive accessibility events only from certain packages.
    info.packageNames = PACKAGE_NAMES;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}
```

In the sample service, this is called from onServiceConnected to initialize the service and subsequently to change the types of feedback being provided.

Comment: The OP specifically said they need to dynamically set the serviceinfo values. onServiceConnected is only called once when the system has successfully bound to the service, it won't be called again